# Setting the logging level in Hadoop to WARN

Tags: logging, hadoop

I've tried numerous ways of setting the logging level in Hadoop to WARN, but have failed each time.
Firstly, I tried to configure the log4j.properties file by simply replacing "INFO" with "WARN" everywhere. No result.

Next, I tried to give Hadoop UNIX commands (in accordance with http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/commands_manual.html#daemonlog):

$ hadoop daemonlog -setlevel

Is it possible that one actually has to alter the SOURCE CODE to make it work? Logging is often quite simple to control, in most cases a slight adjustment of the logging properties usually does it...

Comment: By "everywhere" what do you mean? Are you saying that using `log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=WARN` doesn't do what you want? I'd also be wary of increasing the level to `WARN` unless you're darn sure everything essentially always works.

Comment: For instance, my log4j.properties file now includes the following lines: log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=WARN
hadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN                                                    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSNamesystem=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2=${hadoop.metrics.log.level}

Answer (score 9):

I rather use

> HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,DRFA

in hadoop-env.sh

or you can use hadoop.root.logger in log4j.properties

DRFA will allow the logs to go into the File Appender rather than Console -> System.err/out.

Comment: for use with the hadoop cli one can enable log level for that session by:
{code}
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console
hadoop fs -ls /
{code}

Answer (score 6):

To change the log levels dynamically, so that restart of the daemon is not required use hadoop daemonlog utility.

```
    hadoop daemonlog -setlevel hostname:port className logLevel
```

For example to change the log level of datanode logs to WARN.

```
    hadoop daemonlog -setlevel hostname:50075 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode WARN
```

Answer (score 4):

Apache hadoop documentation is a bit misleading. If you are debugging issues you can change the log level on the fly using the below steps. You should mention the package name rather than the file name.

Example: For Namenode: hadoop daemonlog -setlevel lxv-centos-01:50070 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode DEBUG

For Resourcemanager yarn daemonlog -setlevel lxv-centos-01:8088 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager DEBUG

The above setting goes away when you restart the processes. This is a temporary solution for debugging issues.

Answer (score 3):

The default log level can be adjusted by modifying the `hadoop.root.logger` property in your `conf/log4j.properties` configuration file. Note that you'll have to do that for every node in your cluster.

Example line in `conf/log4j.properties`:

```
hadoop.root.logger=WARN,console
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if exec `HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,console`, nothing changed;
2. if ecec `export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,console`, **it works;**

I have test above command on my hadoop-3.1.3.

```bash
[app@hadoop01 datax-202210]$ HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,console
[app@hadoop01 datax-202210]$ hadoop fs -cat /base_province/* | zcat
2022-12-18 16:54:04,965 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
3       山西    1       140000  CN-14   CN-SX
4       内蒙古  1       150000  CN-15   CN-NM
```

```bash
[app@hadoop01 datax-202210]$ export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,console
[app@hadoop01 datax-202210]$ hadoop fs -cat /base_province/* | zcat
3       山西    1       140000  CN-14   CN-SX
4       内蒙古  1       150000  CN-15   CN-NM
```